# Source fields are not mapped - migration error

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I am migrating from magento 1.9.2.4 to magento 2.1.6. While run data migrate command I got below error

```
[2017-05-18 12:38:48][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: customer_eav_attribute. Fields: is_used_for_customer_segment
.............................................
.............................................
[2017-05-18 12:53:38][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: cms_page. Fields: published_revision_id,website_root,under_version_control
```

I have added below content into map-eav.xml ( source->field_rules ) for fixing the above error

```
<ignore>
    <field>customer_eav_attribute.is_used_for_customer_segment</field>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <field>cms_page.published_revision_id</field>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <field>cms_page.website_root</field>
</ignore>
<ignore>
    <field>cms_page.under_version_control</field>
</ignore>
```

first error got fixed but the second error still come, how to solve this?

Comment: Still I am facing the first error. Please help for it

Comment: have you add ignore field instruction in map-eav.xml?

Comment: I have Fixed it.

Comment: glad you got!..

Comment: I am facing similar error "[2019-02-22 06:09:03][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: catalog_eav_attribute. Fields: is_visible_on_checkout" . I have added <ignore<datatype>catalog_eav_attribute.is_visible_on_checkout</datatype</ignore> this code in map-eav.xml file but still getting error.Help me!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Second error is generated because all three fields of cms_page you've mentioned above are not default fields**

***All of three fields were created by a custom module.***

So you have to remove custom module fields as described below using **map.xml** file:

```
<source>
    <field_rules>
            <ignore>
                <field>cms_page.published_revision_id</field>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <field>cms_page.website_root</field>
            </ignore>
            <ignore>
                <field>cms_page.under_version_control</field>
            </ignore>
    </field_rules>
</source>
```

Comment: What can I do if it still throws the error after entering the fields to be ignored?